# Eating Only Cereals at Night?

Tags: weight-loss

I just want to ask if eating only cereals at night is fine?

Since, I spend most of my day at work and my weeknights life at home is like to eat and sleep for the next day, I thought I could just eat light meal at night. When I get home, I spend at least 4 hours watching or something before sleeping. But since diet cereals tastes booooring, I eat the Kellogg's Frosties which is pretty sweet. So I that a fine routine at night?

Comment: Fine for what? Losing fat, gaining muscle, staying full, keeping healthy, etc...

Comment: Losing fat in a healthy way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to 'lose fat in a healthy way' you need to track your food energy intake (using either calories or kilojoules), and consistently eat a deficit. There are lots of questions on this site on how to calculate your energy requirements.

If you are eating a deficit, and are getting enough micro- and macro-nutrient, then as long as you track your cereal intake, it is no better or worse than any other food. It might not leave you as full as other foods, and excess intake might limit your choices at meal times.

Answer (score 1):

Eating cereal at night is fine, although the additional carbohydrates may get stored as fat over time if you eat too much and then sleep.  Whilst you sleep your metabolism slows down significantly and your body is not using the energy from the cereal, therefore your body may start storing this as fat.  Since your aim is weight loss, try eating 2 hours before bed and drink water to fill you up if you're still hungry.  As an additional note Frosties are full of sugar, you could try switching to cornflakes and use a calorie free sweetener such as Canderel.

Comment: I'd recommend dropping the sugar without replacing the sweetener.. losing fat while maintaining a sweet tooth makes the job a lot harder. A change of taste is very important - get into complex grains!